# Flutter conditional statement always renders the true

Tags: flutter

I have been struggling since I am new to flutter. I am trying to generate a list with total of 10 items, I would like to have 5 of the items the border radius be blue while the other 5 will becolor yellow, only the color blue renders not the other one. Please help. Here's my code.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVuTg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change anywhere the variable `unread` (moreover it is marked as `final`). I don't understand all of your code, but I think you can replace this line `color: unread ? Colors.blue : Colors.yellowAccent` with `color: d < 5 ? Colors.blue : Colors.yellowAccent`. The first 5 items will have blue border, the next five will have yellow color.

PS: This statement doesn't make sense `unread ? 5 : 5`. If `unread` is true then  the 'first' 5 will be returned, otherwise the 'second' 5 will be returned. In both cases you will have always 5. If you want to generate 10 items you can use `List.generate(10, (d){....})`

Answer (score 0):

Though it took me time to understand what you want, implementing it would require you to change the value of `unread` either on a trigger of somekind of a button or something by using `setState(() {})` or any state manager you'll be using.

P.S Please paste code instead of images.